# Selecting random div for auto fade in and fade out

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, random, fade

Currently, this code is auto fade in and fade out div by selecting the div element the way they were arranged (consecutive order). What I want to do now is to make the selector in random, I want to fade in a random div and after fading it out it will pick another random div and infinite loop the process. Since I'm new in jQuery and so confused, I also want to know your opinion on how to put this such process on a If Else statement in the easiest way. Like for example, I will get the value of a number

```
int num = 1;
If(num == 1){
<!-- Do the process-->
}
Else {
<!-- Do another process by selecting from another set of divs-->
}
```

Here is the code:

```
    jQuery.fn.nextOrFirst = function (selector) {
    var next = this.next(selector);
    return (next.length) ? next : this.prevAll(selector).last();
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('div.mb').fadeOut(500);

    var fadeInTime = 1000;
    var intervaltime = 3000;
    setTimeout(function () {
        fadeMe($('div.mb').first());
    }, intervaltime);

    function fadeMe(div) {
        div.fadeIn(fadeInTime, function () {
            div.fadeOut(fadeInTime);
            setTimeout(function () {
                fadeMe(div.nextOrFirst());
            }, intervaltime);
        });
    }
});
```

Divs:

```
 <div class="boxes">
      <div class="mb one">1-------------one</div>
      <div class="mb two">2-------------two</div>
      <div class="mb three">3-------------three</div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is exactly what you want but can be modified:

```
var mb = $('.mb'),   
mbl = mb.length;

mb.hide();
rand();

function rand(){
  var r = getRand(0, mbl);

  mb.eq(r).fadeIn('slow', function(){
    $(this).fadeOut('slow', function(){
      setTimeout(rand, 200);
    });
  });
}


function getRand(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) + min);
}
```

Comment: Hi Tom, every time I try this at JSFIDDLE it works fine but when I transfer it into html file it doesn't work. I found it weird, or maybe I missed something or what. Can you please help me?

Comment: try wrapping the whole thing in $(document).ready(function(){}); https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

Comment: I'm new in jQuery, thanks to you now I know that I have to wrap it before it works. Now it runs smoothly!

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the nextOrFirst function to something like:

```
   jQuery.fn.nextOrFirst = function (selector) {
    var xCount = selector.size();   
    return  Math.floor(Math.random() * xCount ) + 1;
}
```

Instead of getting the next of first div, this gets a count of all of the divs,
 and pics a random number between 1 and X(the number of divs with your selector)

Comment: I understand your point but its not working with the code above, can you please show me an example here https://jsfiddle.net/ ?

Comment: It shows only 1 div and stop showing again. Any update please?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this,Hope it helps

```
     var c=$(".boxes div");
     setInterval(function(){

     $.each(c,function(a,z){
          $("div[class='"+(z.className)+"'").fadeIn();
     });

      var item = c[Math.floor(Math.random()*c.length)];
      var u=item.className;

      $("."+u).fadeOut();
      $("div[class='"+u+"'").fadeOut(1000);

   }, 3000);
```

EDIT:

```
var c=$(".boxes div");
 setInterval(function(){
 $.each(c,function(a,z){
    $("div[class='"+(z.className)+"'").hide();
 });
 var item = c[Math.floor(Math.random()*c.length)];
 var u=item.className;
 $("."+u).fadeOut();
 $("div[class='"+u+"'").show().fadeIn(1000);

 }, 2000);
```

FIDDLE LINK: https://jsfiddle.net/bv0jj4wp/29/

Comment: This one works, but It shows all the div element. How to show only one div at a time? and set an interval before the next div to fade in?

Comment: @vnylng Check the answer,i have updated it and also the fiddle link.Also rate the answer if you found any of the answer usefull!

Comment: The code is not working fine when there's another div element, just changing the selector of my previous code might be better. My previous code works fine, but my problem is how to make the selector random. Do you have any idea Sir?

Comment: @vnylng Ok i can do that,but can you tell what is not working in my edited code,as i have added a 4th div in my fiddle and it is working fine.

Comment: It's now working fine. Anyway, how can I add an interval to your new update? I want it to fade in for 4 seconds, and with an interval of another 4 seconds before showing the next random div.

Comment: @vnylng You mean a total cycle of 8 sec? 4 for fading out?

Comment: No, I mean there should be atleast 4 seconds showing none of the divs before showing the next div. Take a look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/vnylng/Lx2dgagr/ please observe the transition, if fades out totally then next div will fade in again after few seconds. I hope you get my point, thank you for your patience on helping a noob like me.